# Sitefinity Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, sitefinity

I am using Sitefinity 6.X . The requirement is to create a photo gallery.But Sitefinity does not seem to work with javascript /jquery. I am always getting the error "Function Not defined", even though i included references to all jQueries.

Experts help is much appreciated.

Comment: Adding a javascript tag should help you a bit more as there are users who only read questions with that tag. That said, you may check with some of the browser development tools how the js files are failing to load.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Start by doing some research and reporting what have you tried. Here is the [first result](http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/gabesumner/posts/gabe-sumners-blog/2011/09/01/how_to_use_jquery_and_other_javascript_libraries_in_sitefinity) that I've found googling the words `sitefinity jquery`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Sitefinity 6.x  go to Widget section drag JavaScript widget from Script and Style Widget and embed your JavaScript/Jquery. There will be a choice to embed your script in html. Please select "Before the closing body" option or "Where the widget is dropped".

Refresh your page again. You will be able to see your photo gallery /Carousel running.

-Rengaseshan

Comment: Yes you are right.The steps you provided fixed the issue (Srinivas)

Answer (score 0):

First drag and drop the JavaScript widget

Second either link the file or paste your JavaScript code in the widget

Finally, click more options at the bottom and select the option of inserting your code **Before the Closing tag**

**As a rule of thumb always have JavaScript code/files just before the end of the body tag**